# UITableViewCell staying empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to fill a UITableView with the objects of an NSMutableArray which is filled from a table in Parse. The array is definitely being filled (I checked its contents with an NSLog), but the table is staying empty. I have tried A LOT of different ways including the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    PFObject *postsObject = [postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [postsObject objectForKey:@"message"];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    }

    if (tableView == table) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

and the much simpler

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    cell.messageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[postsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

My dataSource methods are:

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return postsArray.count;
}
```

EDIT #2:

My code I'm using to fill my array and reload my tableView

```
PFQuery *findData = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AllPosts"];
    [findData setLimit:1000];
    [findData findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                PFObject *post = object[@"content"];
                NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:post, nil];
                postsArray = array;
                [table reloadData];
            }
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Unable To Load" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong , you are replacing the array with new data whenever you are finding a PFObject  in objects, your code should be like this:-

```
//first alloc your array 
 postsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//Logic goes here
    PFQuery *findData = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AllPosts"];
        [findData setLimit:1000];
        [findData findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (error == nil) {
                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    PFObject *post = object[@"content"];
                    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:post, nil];
                    [postsArray addObject:array];
                    [table reloadData];
                }
            } else {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Unable To Load" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
            }
        }];
```

Comment: Thank you very much your your answer! It is showing more than 1 cell now but the cells all show "(" not the actual post. I will tweak it now and let you know how I go, thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I cannot get the textLabel to only show the content I want. Since it is coming from the NSMutableArray it shows it between brackets and speech marks, for example ( "first post" ), except it's on multiple lines. Do you know how to leave this as the text that I need in there?

Comment: That is because you are printing the entire array. You should print the first and only member of the array in your case, like so:

`if (tableView == table) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] firstObject];
    }` Also I think you should call `[table reloadData]` after the `for` loop ends, not at every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check if the cell object is actually returned. Also put in the following code after the call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`

```
if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
```

This would solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this did not solve my problem though. It appears that none of my UITableView methods are being executed. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: @Dyllan you say UITableView methods are not executing, you need to check few things, 1. tableview `delegates` and `datasource` are set, if no set them see ZeMoon's answer. 2. see if your `postsArray.count` is greater than `0`